# How to delete all the files present in a directory using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I need to delete all the files present in a **particular directory** using **robot framework**.

Comment: It is common to provide context as to why this is an issue for you. For example information about your setup (OS, rights) and what the observed error or situation is. This is often accompanied by a [mcve]. More details on what makes a good question can be read in [ask] of the [help] section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local files? By using the keyword [`Remove Files` in the standard OperatingSystem library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/OperatingSystem.html#Remove%20Files), passing as argument the pattern matching your files.

Remote files? If the target is a Linux machine, connecting over ssh and using the `rm` command.

Comment: I used "Empty Directory" keyword in the standard OperatingSystem library and it worked for me